# Is the sum of geometric multiplicities of non zero eigenvalues also the rank of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is true for many examples I can think of, but can we always say that?

Comment: The rank is equal to the order of the matrix minus the geometric multiplicity of $0$. The sum of the geometric multiplicities of the other eigenvalues is _at most_ this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true in general. For instance, the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
has rank $2$, but the sum of the geometric multiplicities of the non-zero eigenvalues is $1$.

Comment: So rank is at least equal to the sum of geometric multiplicities of non zero eigenvalues?Is there some property of a matrix that can tell us whether dimension of eigenspace (excluding eigenvectors corresponding to $0$ eigenvalue) is equal to the rank?

Comment: Yes, the rank is greater than or equal to the sum of the geometric multiplicities of the non-zero eigenvalues. I believe equality holds precisely when the matrix is diagonalizable.